# Using "of" and "about" interchangeably

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Can I use *of* instead of *about* in the following sentence?

> I'd like to hear your thoughts and recommendations about my decision **of**
>   this company and my resignation petition.

Also, could you tell me whether I can use *on* in place of *of*, if using *of* is correct in this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Of* and *about* sometimes interchange, but they do not do so in your example sentence.  The phrase "my decision of this company" is incorrect (does not make sense) while the phrase "my decision about this company" is grammatically correct, and so would be "my opinion of this company".

Whether it is what you mean to say is less clear.
Decisions about companies are made by persons with authority to make such decisions, and "I'd like..." (or, "I would like", or "I wish") "...to hear your thoughts and recommendations regarding my decision about this company..." might be said by someone who has decided to allow, or not allow, a company to continue in its course.

*Comment* If you want help with wording of sentences, perhaps post questions in [writers.stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: In certain contexts you could make a decision on/about a company even when you have no authority or power to affect the company as such. If you were an investor, for example, your *decision on* [Borders Group, Inc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borders_Group) might have been to sell your shares before they went bust.